Binomial mixed model with conditions only ever 'succeeding'
I've been wrestling with getting some models to converge and make sense and think I've identified the problem, but am now looking for a solution (and if you agree with the "problem").
Starting with a model that looks like this
glmmTMB(Dead% ~ Environment*Treatment + (1|batch), data=assay, family = binomial(link="logit"), weights = TotalCounts)

Dead%: the proportion of dead/total measurements (being dead is a binary 1/'success' for the logistic regression), in this dataset this spans 0%-60% roughly
Environment: 4 level categorical
Treatment: 4 level categorical
batch: 3 batches of experiments
TotalCounts: size of each observation used to produce Dead%

This gives me large coefficient estimates for everything with huge error, Treatment level "vv" is pretty representative:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
    Treatmentvv   20.859   4390.649   0.005    0.996
# also seeing extreme r^2 of > 0.9 (Nakagawa's r2) for the model 

What I'm thinking is the problem is that my experiment control level of Treatment has exactly zero Dead% for two or three of the levels of Environment. This is expected, and experimentally, a good thing. But for the model, I think this is giving it a really hard time causing some cases of complete separation in the data. For example, if I run a cheeky test model where I add a tiny bit of Dead% to each observation:
glmmTMB((Dead%+0.01) ~ ...)

I get outputs that make more sense by the estimate and error, and match up well with the trends I can see by plotting the data, e.g.:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
    Treatmentvv         2.71289    0.52749   5.143 2.70e-07 ***
# a less flashy, but more sensible r2 of 0.4 as well

Sample size for testing all these interactive effects is, frankly, low (n = 6 per combination of Environment:Treatment [which each have 4-levels], from 2-reps in each of 3-batches). But the patterns are fairly dramatic on a plot, so expecting some large effect sizes. Working on adding more to this pilot data, but it won't be much more.
I've also tried just jamming ziforumla=~1 into the binomial logistic regression model, which not surprisingly didn't help. But, hopefully indicates what I'm thinking about - is there a data family or other solution to deal with some conditions that have perfect survivorship (i.e., the outcome Dead% is 0% or if coded in as a two-column success,fail is 0,N)? Although I've entered the response data as proportions (then adjusted by sample size weight), they are fundamentally binary counts (so not thinking to use a beta distribution for example).
Thank you!
